# how to modified xml fields when click on the save button?

Tags: android

hi all according to below code when change the country name and currency if i click on the save button it has to modified when i edit it modified should be appear in the xml tags for this anyone help me  to solve the problem.

xml string :

```
<GetCountries>
<CountryID>10</CountryID>
</GetCountries>
```

method name : `UpdateCountryDetails`

xml string :

```
<UpdateCountryDetails>
<CountryID>10</CountryID>
<CountryName>Zimbabwe</CountryName>
<Currency>Zimbabwe Dollar</Currency>
<GMTDiff></GMTDiff>
</UpdateCountryDetails>
```

Comment: Please explain your question little more.it is hard to understand what you exactly want!

Comment: Where do you get the `CountryName`, `Currency` and `GMTDiff` parts from?

Comment: I think xml file cannot be write which is in assest folder. Better you can use SQLite Database for inserting and updating your records after clicking save button.